# How to select columns of a dataset using a List<String>

Tags: apache-spark

I have a `List<String>` containing strings of column names.
I want to be able to pass the list to a `select()` method on a dataset.
How to achieve that ?
I know that it is only possible to pass columns to `select()` but how to do it with `List<String>` ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list to select multiple columns. The function accepts the first element as a string and the second parameter as a sequence of strings.

```
  val list = List("col1" , "col2")
  df.select(list.head ,list.tail : _*)
```

Kindly mark it as a solution, if it has answered your question correctly

Comment: in JAVA please!